# Do I need to use toString() inside a ${}?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an object `x` which implements `toString()`, and I want to print it via:

```
console.log(`${x.toString()}`);
```

Can I always safely omit the `.toString()` part?

Of course, it doesn't have to be solely for printing.

For example, I might just want to format some string for later use:

```
const str = `x = ${x.toString()}, y = ${y.toString()}`;
```

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23879341/method-vs-basic-js-should-i-use-tostring-parseint-jquery

Comment: @Yousaf: I've observed the same results in various different scenarios, and that is why I'm asking this. I want to know if this behavior is guaranteed.

Comment: It depends on your datatype if x is a JSON then you cannot use toString(). If you could provide more explanation to like a code snippet it will help us to provide the answer

Comment: @Vic: I have. Please read the comment that I wrote in response to someone else's same question, right above your own comment.

Comment: @KrkRamaKrishna: Please read my comment above (3rd from the top).

Comment: _"Template literals are **string literals** allowing embedded expressions. ... The default function just concatenates the parts into **a single string**. ..."_

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed not necessary:

```
const obj = {
    toString() {
        console.log("Calling toString");
        return "a";
    }
};
`${obj}`; // console.log "Calling toString"
```

Comment: I suppose you mean "indeed"? Also, do you know of any official documentation of JS which states that this behavior is guaranteed by the language standard?

Comment: [12.2.9 Template Literals](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-template-literals) -> [12.2.9.6 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-template-literals-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

Comment: @goodvibration It is indeed guaranteed. See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString): _Every object has a toString() method that is automatically called when the object is to be represented as a text value or when an object is referred to in a manner in which a string is expected._

Answer (score -2):

The content of the `${ }` should not be a string, that's the whole point. It should be a variable, a function, anything else than a string :).

The variable or whatever you use can of course have a string as its output. That's not controlled from the template string itself, but from the individual variable.

EDIT: Some misunderstood that I was talking about what you input and not what the template expression outputs. If your input is a string, including x.toString() you're doing it wrong, because that's a pleonasm. Butter on the butter.

It's good practice to do what you have to do with your variables or methods before you put them in the template literals.

Comment: So if for example, we have a `name` and `age` variables, we shouldn't use them in a template string like so - `\`My name is ${name} and I am ${age} years old\``?

Comment: That was not what I meant. I wrote that inside the variable goes a variable. Not a string as in a "word".

Comment: The OP is also referring to variables and not to string literals (not my downvote).

Comment: So you shouldn't put say `My name is ${user.getFullName()}.` then?

Comment: @Quentin I'm not talking about the output, but about the input. What you put into the template expression. There's a distinct difference between a) using a variable, method, function or object key that _outputs_ a string value and b) executing a completely unnecessary string conversion inside of the template expression, when that instead should be done when the variable is declared or updated. I wrote "it should be a variable, a function" and still Quentin manages to ask about a ... function (getFullName()).