# How to decrease an HTML element's X position in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to change an element's X position every half-second. I've tried to decrease the amount of pixels, like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var star= document.getElementById("star");
  function moveStar() {
    star.style.left -= "100px"
  }
  setInterval(moveStar, 500)
}
```

I know this doesn't work, but I don't know what does. Any suggestions?

---

Thanks to @ScottMarcus for answering!

Comment: You can't subtract strings. Convert the position to a number with `parseInt`, subtract the pixels, append `px` to it, and store that back in the style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS `left` property takes a string as a value (i.e. "100px"). You can't do math with strings. You'll need to convert the current `left` value to a number, do the math and then concatenate the "px" back on to the end.

Also, as long as you place your `script` just before the closing `body` tag and you don't need access to external resources (like images), then you don't need to set up an `onload` event handler and can just place your code there because by the time the parser reaches the closing body tag, all the HTML for the DOM will have been parsed in to memory.

```js
var star= document.getElementById("star");

function moveStar() {
  // Get the integer portion of the left property
  // and do math on that and then add back the "px"
  // to set the new value. It's a best practice to
  // always specify the second optional argument to
  // parseInt, which is the radix (or the base numeral
  // system that you want used, so you don't accidentally
  // treat the initial value as a hex or octal. Here, we 
  // want base 10.
  leftNumber = parseInt(getComputedStyle(star).left, 10);
  star.style.left = (leftNumber - 50) + "px";
}
setInterval(moveStar, 500)
```

```css
#star { width:100px; position:absolute; left:100%; height:50px; background-color:skyblue; }
```

```html
<div id="star"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you currently have will not work because "100px" is not a number.

There are a few solutions to this.

One is to use regex to remove the "px", then subtract the number and then append "px" back to the it like so:

```
let xPos = Number(star.style.left.replace("px",""));
xPos -= 100;
star.style.left = xPos + "px";
```

Another way is to use `parseInt`, like barmar mentioned:

```
//Specify the radix to represent base 10.
let xPos = parseInt(star.style.left, 10);
xPos -= 100;
star.style.left = xPos + "px";
```

Note that for this scenario we are probably safe doing this, but `parseInt` can bring problems when parsing strings with non-numerical characters in it.

`parseInt` isn't this magical function that removes all unnecessary letters  and/or symbols from a string to make it a number. It has rules to go with it - so be careful and read the [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) article on it.

One more thing you can do is store a number for the position, then subtract that and use that to assign the position of your element. This method is usually used in games for ease of access to the position. I show your entire code for this one to prevent confusion on where to place the solution's code:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var star = document.getElementById("star");
  //You can use parseInt to find the actual value, but this is a demo that assumes you know stars starting position. If you don't use `parseInt` or the methods I mentioned above.
  let xPos = 1000;
  function moveStar() {
    xPos -= 100;
    star.style.left = xPos.toString() + "px";
  }
  setInterval(moveStar, 500)
}
```

Comment: *I use .toString() for best practices, but it isn't necessary since JavaScript typically converts numbers to strings when appending non-number values to them.* <-- There isn't anything wrong with using `.toString()`, other than it's not a best practice and not necessary. Any time (not typically) you concatenate a string with a non-string, the non-string will be converted to a string.

Comment: Ah, I see your point there. I use it here to demo how the value will change to a string after being concatenated with `"px"`.

Comment: As I say, it's not "wrong", it's just redundant. And, certainly not a best practice (so better to not tell people that).

Comment: Yea, I looked it up and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23879551/14409978) answer it's actually `97%` slower! An oopsie on my part, sorry.

Comment: I don't think that would be a factor unless you are doing many thousands of calls on it. The thing is that since you are going to have to concatenate anyway, that will do the conversion for you. Calling `.toString()` on top of that is just unnecessary in this case.

Comment: True, `DRY` (or at least non-redundancy) is very important in programming... not only for code readability but also for best practices and sometimes performance, even.

Comment: Also, read my comments about the best-practice for using `parseInt()`. That one really is a best-practice and you can easily run into problems if the string you are trying to use `parseInt()` on starts with `"0x"` or `"#"`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus yes. In this case we are probably safe, but it *would* be a good idea to alert that problems can arise when doing this in other situations.